# can't open Interface Builder when updated to mac os x 10.7.3

Tags: macos, interface-builder

I updated my macbook to mac os x 10.7.3(11D50b).Then when I build my project under Xcode3.2.5,
errors occurred:

/Volumes/DATA/Work/Untitled/MainWindow.xib:0:0 ibtool failed with exception: Interface Builder encountered an error communicating with the iPhone Simulator. If you choose to file a crash report or radar for this issue, please check Console.app for crash reports for "Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool" and include their content in your crash report.

The Interface Builder app can't be opened too.Maybe Apple didn't support IB any more? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the error was gone yesterday. Maybe reboot the computer can solve this problem.